# Auto filter in excel fails when output is empty(it brings all when output is empty)

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I am using following code for auto filter. And its working fine. Problem is if output value empty the filter give all the values. I am looking for if out empty it ll show empty rows.

```
Sub filter()
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       Dim Location As String
       Dim due As String
       Sheets("sheet2").Activate
       due = Range("b14").Value
       Location = Range("a14").Value
       Range("a16:j1000").ClearContents
       Sheets("Sheet1").Select
       Range("a1:j1000").Select
       Selection.AutoFilter
       ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$j$1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=due
       ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$j$1000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Location
       Range("c2:i1000").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Sheets("sheet2").Activate
       Range("b16").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial
       Sheets("sheet1").Select
       Selection.AutoFilter
       Sheets("sheet2").Select
       Range("b16").Activate
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copying of all data in a filtered list when the filter shows no results is a known bug. Typically, I use `Application.Subtotal(103, ...)` ([SUBTOTAL Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010342929.aspx)) to check for visible records before performing any operations on a filtered list.

```
Sub filter()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Location As String, due As String

    With Sheets("sheet2")
        due = .Range("b14").Value
        Location = .Range("a14").Value
        .Range("a16:j1000").ClearContents
    End With

    With Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1:j1000")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=due
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Location
        With .Offset(1, 2).resize(.rows.count - 1, 7)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then _
                .Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("b16")
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    With Sheets("sheet2")
        .Activate
        Range("b16").Activate
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've tested this on sample data with success. Be careful with using a string (e.g. *due*) when comparing dates.

This is especially important when using VBA to filter a list and subsequently delete the visible records as no visible records will result in your entire data matrix being deleted. Further, there is no `UnDo` from this when run from a macro.

Comment: @ser3766722 - BTW, you can use *3* or *103* as the *function_num* in `SUBTOTAL`; both will only count visible values. I typically use *103* because it reminds me that I am especially concerned with counting visible values only.

Comment: where do i set filter range?. Range("c2:i1000").Select

Comment: @user3766722 - When you use a `With ... End With` clause, anything prefixed by a period within it refers to the range or worksheet you have specified. In the above I used `With Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1:j1000")` then used `.AutoFilter` within it so you would probably want to use `With Sheets("sheet1").Range("ac1:i1000")`. [With...End With Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

Comment: Yes filter range is a1:j1000, but i don't want to bring from a. I just want searching value should a1:j1000 and output should display from c2:j1000 only. You can refer my code Range("c2:i1000").Select
       Selection.Copy

Comment: @user3766722 - Thank you for clearing that up. I've adjusted the `.Offset` command and used `Resize` to narrow the referenced columns. I'm still not sure whether you mean C2:J1000 or C2:I1000 but if I've made an error you know where to correct it.